# How to get the same out of php hash with C#

Tags: c#, php

I have been working, trying to get a C# equivalent of a PHP API, I was getting error message as invalid hash, so I decided to break the code in parts and check the out put of the individual part for both PHP and C#.
Below is what I got:

The code and out put of php ref:

```
$ref = time().mt_rand(0,9999999);

----Out put as at the time it was tested----
14909496966594256
```

In my C# code for ref is as follows:

```
string refl = (DateTime.UtcNow .Subtract( new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0))).TotalSeconds + rnd.Next(0, 9999999).ToString();

----Out put as at the time it was tested----

1490602845.686821282389
```

The php hash out put with the following variables is as follows:

```
$task = 'pay';
$merchant_email_on_voguepay = 'merchant@example.com';
$ref = '14909496966594256';
$command_api_token = '9ufkS6FJffGplu9t7uq6XPPVQXBpHbaN';
$hash = hash('sha512',$command_api_token.$task.$merchant_email_on_voguepay.$ref);

----Out put ----
1cee97da4c0b742b6d5cdc463914fe07c04c6aff8d999fb7ce7aaa05076ea17577752ecf8947e5b98e7305ef09e0de2fed73e4817d906d6b123e54c1f9b15e74
```

Then the C# out put using the same variables and the same PHP ref out put

```
 const string task = "Pay";
 const string command_api_token = "9ufkS6FJffGplu9t7uq6XPPVQXBpHbaN";  
 const string merchant_email_on_voguepay = "merchant@example.com"; 

     Random rnd = new Random();
     string refl = "14909496966594256";
     string hash_target = (command_api_token + task + merchant_email_on_voguepay + refl);

     SHA512 sha512 = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed();

     var bytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hash_target);
     string cryString = BitConverter.ToString(sha512.ComputeHash(bytes));
     string hashD = (cryString).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLower();

  ----Out put ----
 551b057b64f49fc6bd7d428a8e3c36ddaab5e468fd5f9042ad5d4a4fa50349e5312ad2097b4e46d1e74a5a3f4e843848352edb0ea7073dd1cd53b1c4c14ab286
```

Here I discovered that the out put of my C# is different from that of php. so what could be the problem with my code, I will like to get the same out put of that of php using the same variables.

Any good idea to resolve this is welcome.

Comment: You can not generate the same random number at the same time in two different places.

Comment: and the implementations of php: `mt_rand` (a mersenne twister type generator) and Microsoft.NET `Random`, a Knuth-subtractive based routine, are not identical. this means even with the same seed, they will never create the same sequence. Both are not recommended for use with cryptograpy as they're too predictable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your C# code, the value of `task` is `"Pay"`.
In the PHP code it's `"pay"`.

Different input values will, naturally, not hash the same.

Comment: Sure was the problem, I changed "Pay" to "pay" and I got the same out put